# Display international currency

Tags: internationalization, globalization, currency

What is the globally accepted way of displaying international currencies?

For example: US$20, $20, $20 (US), €20, 20€, etc?

If there are many ways to show each currency, what is a good general way of showing currency?

Comment: Also note that not all currencies divide their base unit into 100ths, like the USD - 100 cents to the dollar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a popular issue around here. See if any of these help you out:

[Best Practice - Format Multiple Currencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784794/best-practice-format-multiple-currencies)

[Proper currency format when not displaying the native currency of a culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850673/proper-currency-format-when-not-displaying-the-native-currency-of-a-culture)

[Currency formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071273/currency-formatting/1071302)

Answer (score 5):

I didn't find any single way. That said:

- Show the amount (obviously)
- Show the ISO currency code
- Optionally show a user-friendly symbol

Don't rely on $ or £ -- several currencies use these symbols. ISO currency codes make it unambiguous. I usually do:

```
[user-friendly-symbol][amount] [iso code]
```

For example, `$100 USD` or `€2,000,000 EUR`

For the thousand separator, I usually take the local user's preference, rather than trying to figure out if that currency is generally formatted with , or .

See [ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)

Answer (score 3):

[ISO Currency Codes](http://www.iso.org/iso/support/currency_codes_list-1.htm) are *the* standard, although you might want to special-case certain common currencies (eg, USD, GBP, JPY, EUR etc) and display their symbols too.

Comment: Updating to 2021: https://www.iso.org/iso-4217-currency-codes.html

Answer (score 3):

[ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's generally accepted this is the best way to do it:

```
USD$30
AUS$40
```

And these currencies are displayed like this by default:

```
£20 
€20
```

Answer (score 0):

The ISO 4217 currency code plus the value. So USD20, EUR20.

Answer (score 0):

I do not work in this field but I believe it should be displayed with a 3 letter code after the sum like :

```
  20 EUR
 105 GBP
86.4 USD
```

There are so many countries using dollars, francs (except France, using euros now) and so on
There is still the problem of the separators:

```
1,000,000.00 USD but
1 000 000,00 EUR here in France
```