# Culture Specific Currency for a given culture

Tags: javascript, c#, currency, cultureinfo

So I was working on a website and I was using the following Javascript code

```
UsdAmount.toLocaleString(siteCulture,
      {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'})
CadAmount.toLocaleString(siteCulture,
      {style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD'})
```

And it was working fine with expected results

So that

```
Culture     Currency    Output
en-us       USD         $123.45
en-us       CAD         CA$123.45
en-ca       USD         US$123.45
en-ca       CAD         $123.45
```

But this function does not work in Safari, therefore I can not use it.

So I figure I will just do it on the server side in C# and pass the string

But that does not seem to work for two reasons

1. I can't pass two cultures, a system culture and a currency culture
2. Doesn't seem to work any way since

   ```
   4.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-us")) ==> "$4.00"
   4.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-ca")) ==> "$4.00"  // No CA$
   ```

So anyother ideas on formatting currency that works across all browsers?

Comment: Preparing on serverside is always a good idea. May implement your own rules?

Comment: right now I am looking into regular expression... the issues are I don't know the international rules to follow

Comment: In  countries with the euro its 123, 45€ . Thats all i can help you (dont know C and Regex ... )

Comment: There is a currency symbol and there is an ISO code. Are you looking for something like new RegionInfo("en-ca").ISOCurrencySymbol ?
Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850673/proper-currency-format-when-not-displaying-the-native-currency-of-a-culture

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on a server that supports WinRT (Windows 8 or later) then you can use the [currency formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting.CurrencyFormatter) which will do what you want.